# How to directly open my app activity on receiving request from server?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a taxi driver app in android. When passenger requests for a ride, the request is posted to the server. Now, the server sends the request to the nearby taxi driver. Driver app has an activity with siren which has to be triggered on receiving the request. So, whenever a request arrives, I have to show the siren activity with siren sound. How can this functionality be achieved? I have to show the activity even if the driver app is in background.

Thanks.

Comment: Use FCM and GCM for achieve this functionality, when message arrive than move to your siren activity.

Comment: Use push notification to receive request, For push notification I suggest you to use **[FCM]** (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Comment: I am trying to achieve it using FCM. Will FCM invoke my activity if my app is in background? @LucaKiebel

Comment: Yes absolutely, This will open your first activity that you have defined in Manifest action launcher.

Answer (score 2):

- User GCM/FCM to send the request from server to the client app.
- when you receive the callback in your onReceive method

  fire an intent with the following code;

  ```
      Intent i = new Intent(this, destinationActivity.class);
      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      startActivity(i);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

you need use [socketIo](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) for connect real time to server. This is the best and cheapest way.

Of course you can use FCM, but for a certain amount of the request is free and then it will be paid

Answer (score 0):

Server cannot  directly send request to application. It just responses to incoming requests, so you have to create something like [Socket](https://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming) in your application to listen the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

start your activity from onMessageReceived() method in fcm when particular message received.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class));
```